# How to Disable Helpdesk Button after Ticket Reached A Certain Stage in Odoo Helpdesk

Tags: python, odoo, ticket-system

I'm currently using Odoo 12.0+e-20181025. At the moment I'm using the Helpdesk module and have been trying to modify it so that it can't be edited after it reached a certain stage. While my team managed to make it so that it can't change stage after reaching a certain stage, we realized that it can still be edited and then saved.

I have read around and saw that most of them suggested that I changed all fields to read-only when it reached a certain stage. The thing is, my form has about 135 fields and while it is certainly a doable approach, I would prefer to just edit the button.

I have tried to look for the button ID and managed to find it, but I couldn't disabled it. I also tried using javascript, which loads as I planned but it can't do what I wanted since I found out that the app loaded the whole view first and then it loads the data. I tried to make it invisible by using Studio but can't do it either.

Is there a way to edit the edit/save button so that I can make it be unavailable after reaching a certain stage?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Would you please share your efforts, code and edit your question with your input, current output, error/warning/log and expected output.

Comment: Okay, I've added that in the question.